# Не могу получить ссылочное поле массива сущности пользователя в EntityFramework6 C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Чтобы не было много текста объясню на картинках. У сущности `User` есть вот такое поле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У этой сущности `FavoritesList` такие поля, здесь лежит массив сущностей `FavoritesListProduct` так называемых избранных товаров пользователя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот здесь уже представлены сами поля сущности `FavoritesListProduct` избранного продукта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот проблема такая что когда я загружаю пользователя и загружаю его корзину и лист избранных товаров, то я загружаю к сожалению только поле `Id` у `FavoritesListProduct`, а мне нужно еще загрузить и артикул `ProductArticle` и еще внутри `ProductArticle` его модель `ProductModel`, которая тоже ссылочная, а вот и сам запрос который я пытаюсь делать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как вы сами понимаете, я пробовал через и Select() и ThenInclude() и AsQueryable() и как только не изворачивался, как правильно сделать запрос? Вот что кстати получается на выходе (сорри за качество, скрин экрана попросил сделать друга):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код текстом, а не скринами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для загрузки связанных данных (related entities), вне зависимости от того, являются они коллекцией или свойством, нужен вызов Include с указанием пути к этим данным. Для примера из задачи:

```
.Include(user => user.ListFavourites.Products.ProductArticle.ProductModel)
```

Про загрузку связанных данных можно прочитать здесь [Eagerly loading multiple levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading-multiple-levels).

А здесь [When to Use Include](https://entityframework.net/when-to-use-include) приведен пример SQL, в который конвертируется вызов Include. Вкратце: каждый Include генерирует в SQL-запросе JOIN к указанной таблице. В нашем случае это будет JOIN к таблице ProductArticle.

Также нужно учесть, что при больших уровнях вложенности может возникнуть проблема производительности [Cartesian Explosion](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/cartesian-explosion-problem-in-3-1/). Для того, чтобы ее избежать, можно подгружать данные в контекст по отдельности. Например, у нас всего 10 товаров (ProductModel), но если мы будем загружать их для 100 ProductArticle, то загрузим 10 товаров 100 раз. Для оптимизации можно загрузить сначала 100 записей ProductArticle без Include с ProductModel, потом выбрать из них уникальные идентификаторы товаров и загрузить в контекст 10 записей по товарам. Примерный код:

```
var articles = context.ProductArticles.ToList();

var productIds = articles
    .Select(a => a.ProductId)
    .ToList();

var products = context.ProductModels
    .Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Можете протестировать разницу в скорости загрузки между двумя вариантами и оценить выигрыш в производительности.